# Webflow 1 to Webflow 2 Migration - WARNING: the bean attribute is no longer supported

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I've inherited an application that is currently using Webflow 1.0.6 and am attempting to upgrade this to Webflow 2.3.4 as an interim step before upgrading to a later version.

I've run one of the flows through the WebFlowUpgrader and it has produced the below output:

**list-asset-flow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webflow:flow xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ns0:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd" start-state="uc1000_SearchAndListStructure">
<webflow:var name="ControllerHelper">
<!-- WARNING: the bean attribute is no longer supported --></webflow:var>
<webflow:var name="ListStructureDataController">
<!-- WARNING: the bean attribute is no longer supported --></webflow:var>
<webflow:var name="ViewElementDetailController">
<!-- WARNING: the bean attribute is no longer supported --></webflow:var>
<webflow:on-start>
        <webflow:evaluate expression="flowScope.ListStructureDataController.init()"/>
<!-- <set attribute="ControllerHelper" value="flowScope.ListStructureDataController.controllerHelper" scope="flow" /> --><webflow:set name="flowScope.ListStructureDataController.controllerHelper" value="flowScope.ControllerHelper"/>
        <webflow:set name="flowScope.ViewElementDetailController.controllerHelper" value="flowScope.ControllerHelper"/>
    </webflow:on-start>
<webflow:view-state id="uc1000_SearchAndListStructure" view="/uc1000_SearchAndListStructure.jsp">
        <webflow:on-entry>
            <webflow:evaluate expression="flowScope.ListStructureDataController.display()"/>
        </webflow:on-entry>
        <webflow:transition on="failure" to="uc1000_SearchAndListStructure"/>
        <webflow:transition on="success" to="uc1000_SearchAndListStructure"/>
        <webflow:transition on="reset" to="uc1000_SearchAndListStructure"/>
        <webflow:transition on="close" to="uc1000_SearchAndListStructure"/>
        <webflow:transition on="uc1025" to="maintain-asset-flow"/>
        <webflow:transition on="uc3003" to="maintain-asset-flow"/>
        <webflow:transition on="uc3003a" to="maintain-asset-flow"/>
        <webflow:transition on="back" to="uc1000_SearchAndListStructure"/>
    </webflow:view-state>
<webflow:subflow-state id="maintain-asset-flow" subflow="maintain-asset-flow">
        <webflow:input name="ControllerHelper" value="flowScope.ControllerHelper"/>
        <webflow:input name="ViewElementDetailController" value="flowScope.ViewElementDetailController"/>
        <webflow:transition to="uc1000_SearchAndListStructure">
            <webflow:evaluate expression="flowScope.ListStructureDataController.searchSubmitt()"/>
        </webflow:transition>
    </webflow:subflow-state>
<webflow:bean-import resource="helper-beans.xml"/>
<webflow:bean-import resource="list-asset-beans.xml"/>
</webflow:flow>
```

**list-asset-beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>

    <!-- For UC1000 Search and list Structures Screen -->
    <bean id="ListStructureDataController" class="uk.co.organisation.application.presentation.controllers.ListStructureDataController" singleton="false">
        <!-- <property name="controllerHelper" ref="ControllerHelper" /> -->
        <property name="civilsReferenceDataProcessProxy" ref="CivilsReferenceDataProcessProxy" />
        <property name="monitorConditionProcessProxy" ref="MonitorConditionProcessProxy" />
    </bean>

    <!-- For UC1025 View structure group Screen -->
    <bean id="ViewElementDetailController" class="uk.co.organisation.application.presentation.controllers.ViewElementDetailController" singleton="false">
        <!-- <property name="controllerHelper" ref="ControllerHelper" /> -->
        <property name="civilsAssetProcessProxy" ref="CivilsAssetProcessProxy" />
        <property name="civilsReferenceDataProcessProxy" ref="CivilsReferenceDataProcessProxy" />
    </bean>

   <!-- For UC3003 Maintain structure group Screen -->
    <bean id="MaintainElementDetailController" class="uk.co.organisation.application.presentation.controllers.MaintainElementDetailController" singleton="false">
        <!-- <property name="controllerHelper" ref="ControllerHelper" /> -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm unsure how to resolve the warning **WARNING: the bean attribute is no longer supported**

Prior to the running through the WebFlowUpgrade upgrade the variables were declared as:

```
    <var name="ControllerHelper" bean="ControllerHelper" scope="flow" />
    <var name="ListStructureDataController" bean="ListStructureDataController" scope="flow" />
    <var name="ViewElementDetailController" bean="ViewElementDetailController" scope="flow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `class`:

```
<webflow:var name="ControllerHelper" class="com.example.ControllerHelper">
```

Comment: I don't think this is a suitable option as you'll notice the beans have various properties pointing to beans defined elsewhere within the application.  I've taken a look at using evaluate and set instead (<webflow:set name="flowScope.ControllerHelper" value="ControllerHelper"/>), however am getting an error when attempting to navigate to pages within the application:   org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException.

Comment: if it's already a bean, then simply use it as `controllerHelper.something`

Comment: that’s my understanding of how it should work.  Is the bean-import sufficient to initialise the beans?  Do I then need to do anything in the flow to set the scope (as throughout it refers to flowScope.BEANNAME ?

Comment: you don't need `flowscope.` this bean should be a Spring bean and available depending on the `@Scope` you have on it

Comment: in your case since it's xml the bean import should be enough